# Question about $a \equiv b \pmod{mn} \Leftrightarrow a \equiv b \pmod{m} \wedge a \equiv b \pmod{n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, congruences

So Knuth's 'Discrete Mathematics' states that:

$a \equiv b \pmod{mn} \Leftrightarrow a \equiv b \pmod{m} \wedge a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

But being a curious human being that I am a tried to prove that and here's my attempt:

$x \equiv y \pmod{mz} \Leftrightarrow \exists_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} kmz = y - x \Leftrightarrow \exists_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} lm = y - x \Leftrightarrow x \equiv y \pmod{m}$, because i put $l=km$.

I can do the same for $z$ and I get that $x \equiv y \text{ (mod z) }$.

Everything came up roses yet I've never used the fact, that $m$ and $z$ are relatively prime. Is my proof incorrect or isn't it necessary for $m$ and $z$ to be relatively prime?

Comment: If $m|c$ and $n|c, $   lcm $(m,n)|c$

Comment: So my proof is correct, but $mz$ might be much bigger than it needs to be? Because $m$ and $z$ are not relatively prime then $\text{lcm}(m,z) \lt mz$, and $\text{lcm}(m,z)$ does the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equivalence in your proof is not correct; that is, 
$(\exists k \in \mathbf{Z}) (kmz = y -x)$ is not equivalent to $(\exists l \in \mathbf{Z})(lm = y-x)$. You only have $$(\exists k \in \mathbf{Z}) (kmz = y -x) \implies (\exists l \in \mathbf{Z})(lm = y-x).$$.

Which "Discrete Mathematics" book by Knuth is this? Do you mean "Concrete Mathematics" with Graham and Patashnik?

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed that :) It's equivalent if they are relatively prime though, and that's what escaped my attention.